# Cannot iterate of a collection of Anonymous Types created from a LINQ Query in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, iteration, anonymous-types

Ok everyone, I must be missing something here.

Every LINQ example I have seen for VB.NET anonymous types claims I can do something like this:

```
Dim Info As EnumerableRowCollection = pDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
Dim Infos = From a In Info _
            Select New With {
                             .Prop1 = a("Prop1"), 
                             .Prop2 = a("Prop2"), 
                             .Prop3 = a("Prop3") }
```

Now when I go to iterate through the collection (see example below), I get an error that says "Name "x" is not declared.

```
For Each x in Infos
 ...
Next
```

It's like VB.NET doesn't understand that Infos is a collection of anonymous types created by LINQ and wants me to declare "x" as some type. (Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of an anonymous type?)  I have added the references to System.Data.Linq and System.Data.DataSetExtensions to my project. Here is what I am importing with the class:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Enumerable
Imports System.Linq.Queryable
Imports System.Data.Linq
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which VB version? This should work in VB10 (VS2010), don't know about earlier.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `Option Infer On` before the `Imports` statements. You may also need `Option Strict Off` depending on if you use it or not. This allows VB.NET to infer the anonymous type.

Comment: While having `Option Infer Off` would make the `For Each` line fail, it would also make the `Dim Infos = ...` line fail, unless `Option Strict` is also off.

Comment: this was driving me crazy! TY!

Answer (score 2):

Prolly doen't help, but this works for me in 2008 & 2010, maybe you need OptionInfer on?

```
 _people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "P1", .Age = 1, .BDay = Now})
        _people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "P2", .Age = 2, .BDay = Now})
        _people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "P3", .Age = 3, .BDay = Now})
        _people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "P4", .Age = 4, .BDay = Now})
        Dim infos = From x In _people _
                    Select New With {.anonName = x.Name, .anonAge = x.Age}

        For Each anon In infos
            Debug.Print("anonName=" + anon.anonName + " anonAge=" + anon.anonAge.ToString)
        Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading from vs 20005 to vs 2008 to vs 2010 the Option Infer Off was turned off, when i turned it on everything worked just fine..

I it is by default turned on on vs 2010 and 2008, but in vs2005 it is not an option!! S